# Problems with DNS

Tags: http, proxy, dns, ping

Good afternoon in my timezone.

I am developing a web appp in J2EE.
This web app is called and access inside a sharepoint portal.
When i enter through the sharepoint portal i can access my application, using chrome developes tools i can see all the HTTP traffic, and i see that the browsers sends a request to the following server that is where my app is running serverprd.enterprisename.com.

But when i use the command line in my windows 7 , to ping the machine(server) , for example :
ping serverprd.enterprisename.com it returns me the following message:
"Ping request could not find host serverprd.enterprisename.com"

I am using a proxy.

Can anyone tells me why this happening ? Why through the browser i can access the server and the ping command does not find me the server ?

With the best regards.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Your proxy server id the one who have an access to outside world. All http requests are sent to proxy server and proxy server does DNS lookup. In case of pin, your host have to do DNS lookup and this operation obviously now allowed ( firewall or so).